# What is the proper way of migrating to C++20?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20

I'm a member of a team that works on the development of embedded software. Currently, we're using [Vivado SDK 2018.2](https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2019_1/SDK_Doc/sdk_getting_started/sdk_getting_started.html) with **GCC 7.3.1** for the development of either bare-metal or Linux applications. And, we're seeking to migrate to C++20 as it is the latest version of the language.

I saw that the GCC [supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#:%7E:text=C%2B%2B20%20features%20are%20available%20since%20GCC%208.) C++20 only after the version GCC 8. So, I'm aware that the current compiler toolchain doesn't support C++20.

Is it possible to migrate to C++20 without updating the Vivado SDK? I was planning to update only the compiler toolchain by replacing the current binaries. Is it the proper way of migration?

Comment: My question is why you won't update the SDK itself? Replacing binaries? Which one? Compiler? What is with all the missing libraries? I personally would prefer to go with an modern toolchain, from editor to linker, even if editor means an up to date vi :-) No idea how your SDK is organized, but mixing things is maybe a startpoint of evil :-) BTW: If you want use C++20 for production, you have to use gcc 11! And even this one is not complete, still features are missing...

Comment: @Klaus thanks for the comment. The main problem is that as of 2019, the Vivado SDK had been replaced with [Vitis](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/vitis/2021-2.html). Hence, the structure of projects had been changed. As we have many previous projects, it is harder to migrate to Vitis. By replacing the binaries, I meant replacing the toolchain's `bin/` folder. I forgot that I should replace the libraries as well. Evil you say, ha? :)